# Query optimization on URL text fields

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm coding an Domain, URL and Regex (like SquidGuard) filter for Squid using the eCAP protocol and i want store all the domains into a postgresql database. The problem is that when i do a search with like, example:

```
SELECT website_groups.id,
       "name",
       description
FROM website_domains
   JOIN website_groups ON website_group_id = website_groups.id
WHERE (website_domains.domain = 'google.com'
    OR website_domains.domain LIKE '%.google.com')
```

the query for 1'605'923 tuples has a lag of 490ms, but this is bad for all the request to squid proxy.

My question is how optimize PostgreSQL to make that query more fast, or I need to use a NoSQL Database (I test with MongoDB and make the query in 609ms with less data).

I tried with FullText search, but this has english tokenize and the data are URLs (www.google.com/query?data1=3), Domains (bing.com) and Regex (.*.cu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to create a column for the reverse domain string and create an index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE website_domains ADD reverse_domain VARCHAR(100);
UPDATE website_domains SET reverse_domain = REVERSE(domain);
CREATE INDEX reverse_domain_index ON 
    website_domains (reverse_domain varchar_pattern_ops);
```

`varchar_pattern_ops` allows `LIKE` to use this index if possible.

The prefix search is done by reversing the pattern as well:

```
... OR website_domains.reverse_domain LIKE REVERSE('%.google.com')
```

You can probably avoid the extra column with a computed index

```
CREATE INDEX reverse_domain_index ON 
    website_domains (REVERSE(domain) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

and the following clause:

```
.. OR REVERSE(website_domains.domain) LIKE REVERSE('%.google.com')
```

But you should try.

Comment: Ohhhh!!! Now make the query in only 12ms Thankssss, finnaly i used the INDEX ufff is very quick, if you may explain me why is so quick in a short answer.....

Comment: The index is based on a search tree, which are good for exact and for prefix matches as well. Searching a tree for an exact match is actually a prefix search. When you make a suffix search (like `.. OR REVERSE(website_domains.domain) LIKE REVERSE('www.google.%')`it should always be slow. Take a look at the query plans, too.